# Have both \limits and normal superscript

Tags: macros, math-operators, subscripts, superscripts

I'd like to define an operator that has both a normal-style superscript and a `\limits` style subscript.

[image: 1]

The obvious solution doesn't work.

```latex
\max\limits_{a}\nolimits^{b}
```

[image]

Comment: Your question without example (MWE), which demonstrate your problem, is unclear. Please add this information! Standard `\max` operator should works on such a way ....

Comment: @Zarko No, it doesn't -- see the edit.

Comment: `$\mathop{\max\limits_{a}}\nolimits^{b}$`?

Comment: @Noone ah right, I didn't think of that, thanks.

Comment: your edit is not complete ... is ti in display math environment or in in-line math. For example  the `\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone} \begin{document}
\[
{\max_{a}}^{b}
\]
\end{document}
` works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really easy, because we need to take care of the possible overshoot of the subscript.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\emaxop}{emax}
\NewDocumentCommand{\emax}{oe{_}}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {\emaxop\nolimits\IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\emaxop_{#2}}{\emaxcomplex{#1}{#2}}}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\emaxcomplex}[2]{\mathop{\mathpalette\emax@{{#1}{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\emax@}[2]{\emax@@{#1}#2}
\newcommand{\emax@@}[3]{% #1 = style, #2 = superscript, #2 = subscript
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\emax@@@{#2}{#3}\else\emaxop_{#3}^{#2}\fi
}
\newcommand{\emax@@@}[2]{%
  \begingroup\m@th
  \sbox0{$\displaystyle\emaxop$}%
  \sbox2{$\displaystyle\emaxop_{#2}$}%
  \dimen@=\dimexpr(\wd2-\wd0)/2\relax
  \sbox4{$^{#1}$}%
  \ifdim\wd4>\dimen@ \dimen@=\dimexpr\wd4-\dimen@ \else \dimen@=0pt\fi
  \operatorname*{emax^{#1\kern-\wd4}}_{#2}\kern\dimen@
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\emax y\quad\emax_{x} y\quad\emax[\mathcal{E}] y\quad
\emax[\mathcal{E}]_{x} y\quad \emax[\mathcal{E}]_{Q^{\gets},Q^{\to}} y
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]